# Include product category in woocommerce new order emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I run an e-commerce store set-up using Wordpress and WooCommerce and am having a little difficulty including product category in my new order email.
Basically when a customer makes a purchase, I receive an email with details of the new order however the product category is not included in the email.

Here is the code in my email-order-items.php file

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
$_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
$item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'], $_product );
?>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php


        // Show title/image etc
        if ( $show_image ) {
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<img src="' . ( $_product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $_product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail') ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) .'" alt="' . __( 'Product Image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;" />', $item );
        }

        // Product name
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item );


        // SKU
        if ( $show_sku && is_object( $_product ) && $_product->get_sku() ) {
            echo ' (#' . $_product->get_sku() . ')';
        }

        // File URLs
        if ( $show_download_links && is_object( $_product ) && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() ) {

            $download_files = $order->get_item_downloads( $item );
            $i              = 0;

            foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {
                $i++;

                if ( count( $download_files ) > 1 ) {
                    $prefix = sprintf( __( 'Download %d', 'woocommerce' ), $i );
                } elseif ( $i == 1 ) {
                    $prefix = __( 'Download', 'woocommerce' );
                }

                echo '<br/><small>' . $prefix . ': <a href="' . esc_url( $file['download_url'] ) . '" target="_blank">' . esc_html( $file['name'] ) . '</a></small>';
            }
        }

        // Variation
        if ( $item_meta->meta ) {
            echo '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true ) ) . '</small>';
        }

    ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $item['qty'] ;?></td>
    <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php if ( $show_purchase_note && is_object( $_product ) && $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true ) ) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Email Order Items
     *
     * @author      WooThemes
     * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
     * @version     2.1.2
     */

    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }

    foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
        $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
        $item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'], $_product );
        $terms = get_the_term_list( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php
                echo ''.$terms.': ';
                // Show title/image etc
                if ( $show_image ) {
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<img src="' . ( $_product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $_product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail') ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) .'" alt="' . __( 'Product Image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;" />', $item );
                }

                // Product name
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item )."something";

                // SKU
                if ( $show_sku && is_object( $_product ) && $_product->get_sku() ) {
                    echo ' (#' . $_product->get_sku() . ')';
                }

                // File URLs
                if ( $show_download_links && is_object( $_product ) && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() ) {

                    $download_files = $order->get_item_downloads( $item );
                    $i              = 0;

                    foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {
                        $i++;

                        if ( count( $download_files ) > 1 ) {
                            $prefix = sprintf( __( 'Download %d', 'woocommerce' ), $i );
                        } elseif ( $i == 1 ) {
                            $prefix = __( 'Download', 'woocommerce' );
                        }

                        echo '<br/><small>' . $prefix . ': <a href="' . esc_url( $file['download_url'] ) . '" target="_blank">' . esc_html( $file['name'] ) . '</a></small>';
                    }
                }

                // Variation
                if ( $item_meta->meta ) {
                    echo '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true ) ) . '</small>';
                }

            ?></td>
            <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $item['qty'] ;?></td>
            <td style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php if ( $show_purchase_note && is_object( $_product ) && $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true ) ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**NOTE:** Untested.

Comment: Hi Rohill, Thanks very much for your input. I added your code and tested it but unfortunatly the output in the email was the same. It could be the case that my themes files are overwriting the template files

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your functions.php

```
function modfuel_woocommerce_before_order_add_cat($name, $item){

$product_id = $item['product_id'];

$_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$htmlStr = "";
$cats = "";
$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

$count = 0;
foreach ( $terms as $term) {
$count++;

if($count > 1){
  $cats .= $term->name;
}
else{
  $cats .= $term->name . ',';
}

}

$cats = rtrim($cats,',');

$htmlStr .= $_product->get_title();

$htmlStr .= "<p>Designer: " . $cats . "</p>";

return $htmlStr;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_name','modfuel_woocommerce_before_order_add_cat', 10, 2);
```